# Mongoose array of Object Id contains only last inserted value

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Basically, this is an Instructors profile, that contains a list of dates the instructor is available. The logged in user- `currentStudent` can Join or withdraw from any of these available days- `fetchedAppointments`. The appointment Schema has a property ***attenders*** an array(of students Joining the meeting) which references the Students schema. Also the Student Schema contains a property ***appointments*** (contains the appointments the Student will attend) which references the Appointments schema.

`listState` holds the state to show if student have booked a particular appointment or not. It is an object containing the list of appointmentsID's as keys and the corresponding boolean values  to indicate if the currentStudent has Joined the given appointment or not.

When I query the Student and Appointments Collections in Mongo shell to notice the behaviour, I noticed the following:

1. When a student Joins more than one appointment,The Student_ID appears in the attenders list of each appointments they have joined in the Appointment collection as expected. However, only the last appointment_ID shows in the appointments list of the Student Collection.
2. When the student withdraw from **one** appointment, he/she is removed from only the attenders list of the appointment they withdraw from(Expected behaviour). On the other hand, In the Student collection the ***appointments*** array becomes empty even if the student Joined more than one appointment.

The behaviour is as expected in the Appointments collection but the Student collection seems to be the one with the issue. Please I will appreciate any advice.

Appointment Schema

```
   var appointmentSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    creator: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref : "Instructor"
    },
    attenders: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Student"
    }
    ],
    date: Date,
    venue:String
})
module.exports=mongoose.model('Appointment',appointmentSchema);
```

Student Schema

```
var studentSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        appointments: [
    
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Appointment"
        }
    ]
    })
    module.exports=mongoose.model('Student',studentSchema);
```

This is the React component that renders the list of appointments by an instructor and the option to join or withdraw:(**I am managing my state with REDUX**)

```
  import React,{Fragment, useEffect, useState}    from 'react';
  import { fetchInstructor }          from '../store/actions/instructor';
  import { editAppointment,
       fetchAppointmentsByInstructor}  from '../store/actions/appointment';
  import { editStudent,
        fetchStudent }                 from  '../store/actions/student';                
    import { connect }                 from   'react-redux';

    const InstructorProfilePage=({match,fetchInstructor,instructor, loading, 
    editAppointment,fetchedAppointments,loadingAppointments,
fetchAppointmentsByInstructor, currentUser, editStudent, fetchStudent, 
currentStudent,loadingStudent})=>{ 
  
    const id=match.params.id;
     const [listState, setListState]= useState({})
    const {firstName,lastName, appointments, profileImage, _id}=instructor;
  
    useEffect(() => {
    fetchInstructor(id);
     },[id])
  
     useEffect(()=>{
     fetchStudent(currentUser.user.id)
            
     },[currentUser])//currentUser.user.id
  
  
     useEffect(()=>{
    fetchAppointmentsByInstructor(id)
     },[id])
  
  
    //Checking if currentStudent has joined an appointment and storing the 
   value as bool
    var initialStateVals=!loadingAppointments &&  
   fetchedAppointments.map(appointment=>{
    return appointment.attenders.some(user=>{
      return  currentUser.user.id && currentUser.user.id===user
    })
    })
    //associating each bool value gotten above with its apointmentID
    var inialStateObjects=!loadingAppointments &&  fetchedAppointments.map((appointment,index)=>{
    let obj= Object.assign({},{[appointment._id]:initialStateVals[index]})
    return obj
    })
    //merging each object gotten above as one (Initial List State)

    var mergedInitialStateObject= inialStateObjects && Object.assign({}, ...inialStateObjects)
  console.log(mergedInitialStateObject)
  
    useEffect(()=>{
    setListState({...mergedInitialStateObject})
    },[fetchedAppointments, currentUser]) 
  
    const handleJoin=(appointmentBody)=>{
    editAppointment({...appointmentBody,attenders:[...appointmentBody.attenders,currentStudent._id]})
    
    editStudent({...currentStudent, appointments: [...currentStudent.appointments,appointmentBody._id]})
    
    setListState({...listState, [appointmentBody._id]:true})
    
  }
  
    const handleWithdraw = (appointmentBody)=>{
         
    let updatedAttenders= appointmentBody.attenders.filter(attenders=>{
      return attenders!==currentStudent._id
    })
    
    let updatedAppointments= currentStudent.appointments.filter(appointment=>{
      return appointment!==appointmentBody._id
    })
    editAppointment({...appointmentBody, attenders:[...updatedAttenders]})
    editStudent({...currentStudent,  appointments: [...updatedAppointments]})
    
    setListState({...listState, [appointmentBody._id]: false})  
  
    }
  
    return (<Fragment><ul className="appointments-list">
         loadingAppointments  ?
           (<Fragment>
           <div>Loading Appointments.....</div>

           </Fragment>) :
           ( fetchedAppointments.map((appointment)=>{
            return <li key={appointment._id} className="dateItem">
                    { new Date(appointment.date).toDateString()} 
            
            {listState && (listState[appointment._id]===false &&
                <span className="ml-3 span-action"
                    onClick={()=>handleJoin(appointment)}>
                  Join 
                 </span>)}
            {listState && (listState[appointment._id]===true &&
                <span className="ml-3 span-action"
                    onClick={()=>handleWithdraw(appointment)}>
                  Cancel
                 </span>)}
              </li>
      
                }))
            }
        </ul>
      </Fragment>)
    }


    const mapStateToProps=state=>{
    return {
      instructor: state.instructor.instructor,
      currentStudent: state.student.student,
        loadingStudent:state.student.loading,
      fetchedAppointments: state.appointment.appointmentsByInstructor,
        loadingAppointments: state.appointment.loading
    }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchInstructor, fetchAppointmentsByInstructor,editAppointment,editStudent,fetchStudent})(InstructorProfilePage);
```

Edit Student Handler

```
 //===Responds to Put request to /api/students/:id in backend
    exports.updateStudent = async function(req,res, next){
        try{
            var student = await db.Student.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {new: true})
             return res.status(200).json(student)
        }catch(err){
            
            return next(err);
        }
    
    }
```

Edit Appointment handler

```
 //===Responds to put request to /api/appointments/:appointmentId in backend
    exports.updateAppointment = async function(req,res, next){
    try{
    var appointment= await Appointment.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 
    req.params.appointmentId}, req.body, {new: true})
     return res.status(200).json(appointment)
    }catch(err){
    
    return next(err);
    }

    }
```

Edit student action

```
 export const editStudent = updatedStudent =>{
       return dispatch => { 
          const path="/api/students/"+updatedStudent._id
                return apiCall('put', path, updatedStudent)
                      .then(res=>{ dispatch
                        (updateStudent(res))})
                      .catch(err=>{dispatch(
                      setAlert(err.message,"warning"))});
                    }
}
```

Edit Appointment action

```
  export const editAppointment = ( updatedAppointment) =>{
    
       return dispatch => { 
          const path=`/api/appointments/${updatedAppointment._id}`
                return apiCall('put', path, updatedAppointment)
                      .then(res=>{ dispatch
                        (updateAppointment(res));})
                      .catch(err=>{dispatch(
                      setAlert("There was an error, couldn't edit appointment info.","warning"))});
                    }
    }
```

Api call function

```
 export function apiCall(method, path, data){
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        return axios[method.toLowerCase()](path,data,config)
            .then(res=>{
             return resolve(res.data)
             })
            .catch(err=>{
            return reject(err.response.data.error);
        });
    });
    }
```

Comment: You need to give at least a sample reproducible code. Include `editAppointment` and `editStudent`. Include everything relevant.

Comment: I have added the `editAppointment` and `editStudent` and also the handlers that responds to the API requests. Reducing the code to a reproducible one could hide the problem I'm facing. I just need some help checking If the way I keep track of listState is a problem, or something else. The problem is I don't know the culprit, but I suspect its from the React code.